# AC600: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing

Tags: drivers

On my Ubuntu 15.04 machine, I have a MediaTek USB Wifi Key, with lsusb data o

```
# lsusb | grep MediaTek
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.
```

I grabbed the drivers from `https://github.com/porjo/mt7601` and modified the `common/rtusb_dev_id.c` and added the line `{USB_DEVICE(0x0e8d,0x7610)},` so the file now reads:

```
USB_DEVICE_ID rtusb_dev_id[] = {
#ifdef RT6570
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x6570)}, /* Ralink 6570 */
#endif /* RT6570 */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f, 0x7650)}, /* MT7650 */
#ifdef MT7601U
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x6370)}, /* Ralink 6370 */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x7601)}, /* MT 6370 */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x760b)}, /* 360 wifi */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x2a5f,0x1000)}, /* Tencent wifi QQ */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x2955,0x0001)}, /* XiaoDu Wifi */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x2955,0x1001)}, /* XiaoDu Wifi */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x2955,0x1003)}, /* nuomi wifi */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x0e8d,0x7610)}, /* Aukey wifi */
#endif /* MT7601U */
    { }/* Terminating entry */
};
```

I rebuilt and installed the module, but it's not picking it up

Any ideas

Comment: Having rebuilt it, I'd expect that you'd have to supply a new signature or key, or both. Isn't that what the message is saying?